# Python(PyCharm) Selenium skipping over lines code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, buffer, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working a project to automate logging into a couple of sites and creating users in those sites. It seems to me Selenium is skipping lines and not waiting for user input in the console. I have notated the areas where it skips with python comment marks. I have also replaced specific information with generalized information. Is there something I need to do to force Selenium to wait on console input or is it a bug? Any advice would be appreciated. Also, I'm relatively new to Python as a whole and any bad practices you see please let me know.  Below is my code so far.

Note: Little backstory. I started on website2 first and ran into a few issues I'm still working through so I moved to website1 and the code is incomplete as I'm building code as I progress through the layers of the site.

```
def website1Login():
    driver.get('website1.com')
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")  # Waits for action
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    searchBox.send_keys(username)
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")  # skips action
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    searchBox.send_keys(password)
    searchBox.submit()


def website1Create():
    webOrExchange = 0
    webOrExchange = input("Select a service: \n" # Skips action
                          "1. Webmail\n"
                          "2. Exchange\n\n"
                          "Service Selected: ")
    time.sleep(10)
    if webOrExchange == 1:
        webmailSelect = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('EmailHosting/Mail/Mailboxes/List.aspx')
        webmailSelect.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        exchangeSelect = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Exchange/Mail/Mailboxes/List.aspx')
        exchangeSelect.click()
        time.sleep(2)


def website2login():
    driver.get('website2.com')
    username = input("Please enter your username: ") # Waits for this action
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('USER')
    searchBox.send_keys(username)
    password = input("Please enter your password: ") # Skips this action
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('PASSWORD')
    searchBox.send_keys(password)
    searchBox.submit()


def website2Create():
    idmSelect = driver.find_element_by_id('Identity Management')  # Selects Identity Management app
    idmSelect.click()
    time.sleep(15)
    createNewUser_Select = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="request_category2"]/ul/li'))  # Selects Create New User
    )
    createNewUser_Select.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()


def main():
    website1Login()
    website1Create()
    # website2login()
    # website2Create()


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, there seems to be some mixup between the *attribute value* within the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) and *variable name* being used.

You have used:

```
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
```

But again, `username` is a *string* variable holding the actual *username* from the *console*.

As per best practices, the variable names should be unique as per their scope.

This step may solve your current issue.

---

### flush the input stream

You can also flush the input stream as follows:

- On *Windows* systems you can use **`msvcrt.getch()`** method from the [**msvcrt**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) module.

  - `msvcrt.getch()`: Read a keypress and return the resulting character. Nothing is echoed to the console. This call will block if a keypress is not already available, but will not wait for Enter to be pressed. If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return '\000' or '\xe0'; the next call will return the keycode. The Control-C keypress cannot be read with this function.
  - Example:

    ```
    import msvcrt
    import sys

    x = input("First Input: ")
    print("First Input: {}".format(x))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # Try to flush the buffer
    while msvcrt.kbhit():
        msvcrt.getch()
    y = input("Second Input: ")
    print("Second Input: {}".format(y))
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    First Input: asdfg
    First Input: asdfg
    Second Input: ;lkjh
    Second Input: ;lkjh
    ```
- On *Unix* systems you can use **`termios.tcflush(fd, queue)`** method from the [**termios**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#module-termios)

  - `termios.tcflush(fd, queue)`: Discard queued data on file descriptor fd. The queue selector specifies which queue: TCIFLUSH for the input queue, TCOFLUSH for the output queue, or TCIOFLUSH for both queues.
  - Example:

    ```
    from termios import tcflush, TCIFLUSH
    import time,sys

    a = raw_input("First input ")
    b = raw_input("Second input ")
    time.sleep(5)
    tcflush(sys.stdin, TCIFLUSH)
    a = raw_input("Third input ")
    b = raw_input("Fourth input ")
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    First Input 1
    Second Input 2
    33
    33
    Third Input 3
    Fourth Input 4
    ```

Comment: `"username"` is a *string* while `username` is a variable that might contain *any data of any type*. Where is *mixup* in this case and about which *best practices* are you talking about? Also how can *input stream flushing* solve this issue?

Comment: @DebanjanB your example code solved my issue thank you. I'm not sure I fully understand it but I will definitely read up on it. I need to go back and clean up my variables. I was pretty sloppy in naming them in the beginning.